# How do i implement .tag when jumping to a posiiton in a scrollview?

Tags: swiftui

I have added the .id(1) to the positions in the scrollview and can get it to work as expected if i add a button inside the scrollview but i want to use a picker to jump to the .id and outside the scrollview.

Im new to this.

I have this code:

if i use this button it works as expected although its placed inside the scrollview...

```
Button("Jump to position") {
                    value.scrollTo(1)
                }
```

This is my picker...

```
// Main Picker
            Picker("MainTab", selection: $mainTab) {
                Text("iP1").tag(1)
                Text("iP2").tag(2)
                Text("Logo").tag(3)
                Text("Canvas").tag(4)
            }
            .frame(width: 400)
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
      

            ScrollViewReader { value in
                
            ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                
                ZStack {
                    
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    // .backgroundStyle(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .opacity(0.2)
                        .frame(width: 350, height:185)
                    //   .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .id(1)
```

Comment: Pleaso do mark the right answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you are mixing here:

1. The `tag` modifier is to differentiate elements among certain selectable views. i.e. `Picker` `TabView`
2. You can't access the proxy reader from outside unless you make it available. In other words the `tag` in the `Picker` and the `ScrollViewReader` does not have a direct relationship, you have to create that yourself:

   ```
    import SwiftUI

    struct ScrollTest: View {
        @State private var mainTab = 1
        @State private var scrollReader: ScrollViewProxy?

        var body: some View {
            // Main Picker
            Picker("MainTab", selection: $mainTab) {
                Text("iP1").tag(1)
                Text("iP2").tag(2)
                Text("Logo").tag(3)
                Text("Canvas").tag(4)
            }
            .frame(width: 400)
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            .onChange(of: mainTab) { mainTab in
                withAnimation(.linear) {
                    scrollReader?.scrollTo(mainTab, anchor: .top)
                }
            }

            ScrollViewReader { value in
                ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {

                    ForEach(1...4, id: \.self) { index in
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .opacity(0.2)
                                .frame(width: 350, height: 500)

                            Text("index: \(index)")
                        }
                        .id(index)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    scrollReader = value
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```

[image]

Comment: struct and classes should always start with an uppercase

Comment: Thanks! Ive got it implemented and working and also thanks for the struct uppercase tip!